# Can there be a proper subset of a Dedekind complete ordered field which is also a Dedekind complete ordered field?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the following statement true?

the statement: Let **K**,**K'** be a Dedekind complete ordered field. If **K'⊂K**, then **K=K'**

In other words, my question is whether there can be a proper subset of **K** which is a Dedekind complete ordered field.

Comment: In other words, can $\Bbb R$ contain a proper subfield isomorphic to $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Elaborating on Hagen von Eitzen's comment: up to isomorphism, $\mathbb{R}$ is the unique Dedekind-complete ordered field, so we're really just looking at subfields of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K'$ be a subfield of $\Bbb R$. Then $\Bbb Q\subseteq K'$.
If $\alpha\in\Bbb R$, then $(-\infty,\alpha)\cap K'$ is a Dedekind cut of $K'$. For Dedekincd complete $K'$, the corresponding number $\beta\in K'$ must be $>x$ for all $x\in K$ with $x<\alpha$ and $\le x$ for all $x \in K'$ with $x\ge \alpha$. Already from letting  $x$ run over all rationals, we see that $\beta=\alpha$. We conclude that $K'=\Bbb R$.